# jquerymobile button clicked goes blue

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm trying to prevent my button from flashing blue after clicking, anyone know what class causes this change? so I can override it

Cheers!

Comment: did you find the correct solution? looking for it too. i dont get it via ui-btn-active...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The class you're looking for is

```
.ui-btn-active
```

Comment: Hey Shane, thanks again! I actually have been using that class everywhere, just got myself confused lol :/ Thought there may have been a 3rd state.

Answer (score 11):

For anyone landing here and wondering what to do with .ui-btn-active, I'd like to build on sqlisers answer with:

```
.ui-btn-active 
{ 
    color: #2F3E46 !important; 
    background: none !important; 
    background-color: #eee !important; 
    text-shadow: 0 /*{a-bup-shadow-x}*/ 
                 1px /*{a-bup-shadow-y}*/ 
                 0 /*{a-bup-shadow-radius}*/ 
                 #ffffff /*{a-bup-shadow-color}*/;  
}
```

Just change the color values to whatever you like.

Comment: .btn-active {} has a default background-image: gradient; applied to it, so you'll need to set background-image: none; on your custom .ui-btn-actives, as Andreas points out.

Answer (score 8):

If this happens on your mobile, I'd suggest adding this to your stylesheet:

```
* {
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
```

This will remove the default tap-highlight function of the webkit browser (on any mobile). Seems to work mostly on Android phones, but it does have affect on iOS devices as well.